# What is the purpose of this construction?

Tags: java, swing

I saw an example of Java program using AWT frame and it contains this code:

```
mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
        System.exit(0);
    }        
});
```

The `new WindowAdapter()` part looks like creating a `WindowAdapter` class instance but the `WindowAdapter() { ... }` part looks like a class (or probably something else) declaration with a method in it. So what exactly is going on here?

Comment: A logical guess would be that when the user closes the Window (perhaps Frame) they want to take notice of the action via an event and do some final processing

Comment: @Mat Adapter classes are classes not interfaces.   They implement the interface method(s) with empty method bodies so the user can override the ones they want without having to explicitly provide the empty ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s an anonymous inner class. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html. In early versions of Java there was disagreement about whether to provide lambdas or not, anonymous classes are a compromise.

The posted code  is an anonymous class extending WindowAdapter, which has do-nothing implementations of various methods. The user has to fill out only those methods that are for events that need to be handled.  Because the class has no relevance anywhere else, using an anonymous class here means  the developer doesn’t have to create a separate class definition for it.